# replace a line in python with exactly same formatting

Tags: python, format

I am trying to **exactly** replace  lines in this `mwe.inp` file:

```
MESH INFORMATION
MESH-TYPE EXPONENTIAL
   IM      R(1)            DX         JRMT      RMT        JRWS      RWS
    1    0.0000010000    0.0206069754    0    2.3607817007  721    2.7773902361
    2    0.0000010000    0.0205809760    0    2.3169999310  721    2.7258822717
    3    0.0000010000    0.0205301413    0    2.2337287219  721    2.6279161434
```

I am using the code:

```
import math

with open("new", 'w') as fout:
  with open("mwe.inp.", 'r') as finp:
    for line in finp:
      if line.startswith("   IM      R(1)            DX         "):
        for qline in range(3):
          fout.write(line)
          line = next(finp)
          inpp = line.split()
          r_ws = round(2.75234333248239 * 1.2, 10)
          r_mt = round(r_ws * .85, 10)
          dx = round(
              math.log(float(r_ws) / float(inpp[1])) / (float(inpp[5]) - 1),
              10)
          inpp[2] = str(dx)
          inpp[4] = str(r_mt)
          inpp[6] = str(r_ws)
          print(inpp)
          str2rp = ("    " + "    ".join(inpp)) + "\n"
          line = line.replace(line, str2rp)
      fout.write(line)
```

which is yielding:

```
MESH INFORMATION
MESH-TYPE EXPONENTIAL
   IM      R(1)            DX         JRMT      RMT        JRWS      RWS
    1    0.0000010000    0.0208476178    0    2.8073901992    721    3.302811999
    2    0.0000010000    0.0208476178    0    2.8073901992    721    3.302811999
    3    0.0000010000    0.0208476178    0    2.8073901992    721    3.302811999
```

Given in `mwe.inp`, space between RMT and JRWS column is different and hence it is not `exactly` replacing the file. I need it to be replaced exactly, because it is an input of fortran program that reads input bu column number.

Also, if `round` is rounding to 9th decimal, everything will be shifted, like:

```
1    0.0000010000    0.0208476178    0    2.8073901992    721    3.302811999
2    0.0000010000    0.020847617    0    2.8073901992    721    3.302811999
3    0.0000010000    0.0208476178    0    2.8073901992    721    3.302811999
```

So, how I can modify the code so that the `new` file is in exactly same format with `mwe.inp`?

**On Needs more focus close vote** Isn't it straight that I just want to create the new files with exactly the same format as the mwe.inp? May I request who voted for close with `need more focus` found multiple problem in one question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math

with open("new", 'w') as fout:
    with open("mwe.inp", 'r') as finp:
        for line in finp:
            if line.startswith("   IM      R(1)            DX         "):
                for qline in range(3):
                    fout.write(line)
                    line = next(finp)
                    inpp = line.split()
                    r_ws = round(2.75234333248239 * 1.2, 10)
                    r_mt = round(r_ws * .85, 10)
                    dx = round(
                             math.log(float(r_ws) / float(inpp[1])) / (float(inpp[5]) - 1),
                         10)
                    inpp[2] = "%.10f" % dx
                    inpp[4] = "%.10f" % r_mt
                    inpp[6] = "%.10f" % r_ws
                    print(inpp)
                    str2rp = f'    {inpp[0]}    {inpp[1]}    {inpp[2]}    {inpp[3]}    {inpp[4]}  {inpp[5]}    {inpp[6]}\n'
                    line = line.replace(line, str2rp)
                    fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you are adding 4 spaces between the values of RMT and JRWS, which in original file is only two spaces.

If you modify the program like shown below, things work out fine.

```
          inpp[4] = f'{inpp[4]}  {inpp[5]}'
          inpp.pop(5)
          inpp[5] = str(r_ws)
```